# MS Power Point 2003: How to play all the slides quickly one after another - just like in a movie?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I have a lot of slides in my PowerPoint application and they all are just like film frames of one motion film, so I want to play back them all very quickly - is it possible in Power Point?

Comment: Maybe you could make a slide show with a small timer. But i doubt it will run as smooth as a 'real' movie. Power Point is simply not designed for this. And i doubt, that you can set a timer smaller than one second.

Maybe try this link: http://gickr.com/

I don't know that page. I've just googled it.

Comment: I see. Thank you. WOW!!! The link you gave me solved another problem that I had - didn't know how to quickly make a gif animation file! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you find better results with MS Windows Movie Maker. See [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-simple-stop-motion-video-using-Windo/).

You will be able to set the frames time.

The smaller "automatically advance slide" timer is 1 second on PowerPoint-2007. I don't know if there are smaller timer on PowerPoint-2003.